# Can API gateway proxy to an HTTP server for more than json?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I'm experimenting with AWS API Gateway as an authentication solution for a private HTTP service and I'm having trouble getting it setup.

I have a dummy node.js serice running within a private VPC with an internal network load balancer in front (note: it's healthy).

I then setup an API and configured a VPC link this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-private-integration.html

The resource URL of the get method points to the DNS name of the internal network load balancer.

When I navigate to the API gateway URL (e.g. https://ABC123.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/), I'm able to get the HTML response of the server (see below). However, the javascript files return a `403 Forbidden`. I expect this has something to do with the path setup.

Rather than just returning a single response (i.e. json API response), is there a way to configure API gateway to return a full blown app which includes HTML, css, and js resources?

---

Here's the dummy code that runs the app:

```
// server.js
var express = require('express'),
app = express(); 
app.use('/', express.static('/home/ubuntu/static/'));
app.listen(8080);
```

the index page - this is the page that loads when I hit the API Gateway

```
<!-- static/index.html -->
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p>This is some text.</p>
<script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: the index page]

This JS fails to load (403) and does not execute.

```
// static/app.js
console.log('Logging from app.js');
alert('WOOT!');
```

[image: console output]

Comment: I'd take a look at https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express

Comment: thanks @RobertoNovelo. I came across this in my research as well. I think this would work well for my homegrown dashboards and projects. However, I'd like to leverage a number of stand-alone 3rd party applications too. The amount of rework to integrate this into aws-serviceless-express might be a bit too much to handle. Ideally I'd like api gateway to serve as an authentication proxy but I might be asking to much?

Comment: Are sources imported from the correct path? what is the complete get url you are trying to fetch app.js from

Comment: I _think_ they are correct. The URL of the app is: `https://API_GATEWAY_ID.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/`. The app.js URL is `https://API_GATEWAY_ID.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/app.js`. Note: `prod` is the stage ID.

My initial thought wast that it had something to do with the Resource definition i.e. [proxy resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-proxy-resource?icmpid=docs_apigateway_console) but I continue to get 403 errors no matter how I set it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your function is being called (and correctly configured) in the Lambda panel on AWS. If your API Gateway is correctly configured, it should appear as a trigger to your lambda function:

[image: lambdaconfig]

After that, you can see your lambda's stats and logs on the monitoring tab:

[image: lambdamonitoring]

You need an event handler function that redirects the API Gateway request to the corresponding resource on your express application, which means you need implement some sort of middle layer to map correctly the API GateWay Requests to your express method/path/parameters/files.

AWS Lambda are functions the are called when an event occurs on services such as API Gateway, SNS, Alexa Skills, etc. I'd try to setup [aws-serverless-express](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express), or use some other service such as Elastic Beanstalk or ECS